# how can i make my own $this->load->view in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, view

the default of CI of loading views is:

```
$this->load->view('path');
```

but what if i wanted to do something like

```
$this->load->adminView('path')
```

then i can prefix the path in adminView followed by the path

how would i do this?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to ../System/Core/Loader.php, line 417 -> 210 (CI 2.10)

```
public function view($view, $vars = array(), $return = FALSE)
{
    return $this->_ci_load(array('_ci_view' => $view, '_ci_vars' => $this->_ci_object_to_array($vars), '_ci_return' => $return));
}
```

change your function name (and maybe some code else) as you wish, be careful!

Comment: i dont want to modify the core. maybe if i created a file called loader.php and place it in application/core it will overwrite it

Comment: i copied the Loader.php into core/Loader.php with the same content and  copied the view function and renamed it to adminView and called $this->load->adminView('path'); in the controller and it worked.

Comment: i think what i'm doing is bad practice, ill find another method, thanks

Answer (score 0):

In `application/core/` make a new Controller:

```
<?php

if(!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Admin_Controller extends CI_Controller
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function load_admin_view($path, $data = '', $return = false)
    {
        return $this->load->view("admin_dir/" . $path, $data, $return);
    }

}

?>
```

Then make your current controller extend this controller:

```
class Page extends Admin_Controller
```

Instead of

```
class Page extends CI_Controller
```

Then you can use:

```
$this->load_admin_view("path");
```